# Creating a FormsAuthentication with userdata inside an ASP.NET MVC Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

I'm trying to create a FormsAuthentication inside a Web API MVC 4 with inserting userdata. I know how to do it on a client side.

```
UserData userData = new UserData()
{
    SiteID = result.UserLite.SiteID,
    UserID = result.UserLite.ID,
    UserName = result.UserLite.UserName,
    SiteName = result.UserLite.SiteName,
    TokenValue = result.BaseSecurityToken.Value,
    FirstName = result.UserLite.FirstName,
    LastName = result.UserLite.LastName,
    Email = result.UserLite.Email,
    LanguageID = result.UserLite.LanguageID
};

FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
         1,
         model.UserName,
         DateTime.Now,
         DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout),
         false,
         Serialize(userData));

string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
```

In my Web API I don't have the object Response.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
```

But it doesn't give me the possibility to add user data.

Comment: That should come under controller code, If I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response
```

`Request` and `Response` objects are core of ASP.NET, they are always **somehow** accessible.